# How to dismiss view from UImagePickerController with custom button?

Tags: iphone, button, uiimagepickercontroller, terminate

I'm using the Zbar scanner SDK which lets me read barcodes. Now the default version stops scanning after one barcode is read and shows you the result. I've made my own UIToolBar with its own Done button because I want it to scan however many times, all of this shall be terminated whenever the user clicks on the "done" button on my UIToolBar. I've made the button, but how do I add the action to the button? It's quite confusing due to the pickerController's involvement and the Zbar SDK.How do I link the doneButton in my overlay to an action that terminates the scanning?

This is the overlay where I've set the Done button.

```
-(UIView*)CommomOverlay  {

UIToolbar *myToolBar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 428, 320, 70)];
[myToolBar setBarStyle:UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent];

UIBarButtonItem *doneButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(doneButtonTap:)];

[myToolBar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:doneButton, nil] animated:YES];
[FrameImg addSubview:myToolBar];
[view addSubview:FrameImg];
return view;
```

This is the barcode scanner SDK's IPC section.

```
 -(void) imagePickerController: (UIImagePickerController*)
 readerdidFinishPickingMediaWithInfo: (NSDictionary*) info {
{

// ADD: get the decode results
id<NSFastEnumeration> results =
[info objectForKey: ZBarReaderControllerResults];
ZBarSymbol *symbol = nil;
for(symbol in results)
// EXAMPLE: just grab the first barcode
break;
// EXAMPLE: do something useful with the barcode data
resultText.text = symbol.data;

// setup our custom overlay view for the camera
// ensure that our custom view's frame fits within the parent frame
// EXAMPLE: do something useful with the barcode image
resultImage.image =
[info objectForKey: UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

// ADD: dismiss the controller (NB dismiss from the *reader*!)
//Delete below in entirety for continuous scanning.
[reader dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: NO];
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to set action of dissmissmodalviewcontroller on done button using selector

Comment: You posted in a comment below that the app is crashing, please post the crash logs so we can get a better idea of what is going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Try to set action of dissmissmodalviewcontroller on doneButton using selector

```
  [doneButton addTarget:self action:@selector(dismiss) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

In dismiss Method

```
 -(void)dismiss
    {

    [self dismissmodalViewController];

    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but it's not working. I've implemented the first line of code in my overlay section. The app actually crashes on start up. Let's forget the specifications, how would I terminate the UIImagePickerController session by use of the done button?